# Django Edited images not showing up after processing in views

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-imaging-library

The website allows user to upload an image and will be edited and shown to the user. (learning to use Pillow for image editing). It gives no error in the terminal, the images are getting saved, but not showing up after edit. Is there issue with how the image is generating? Or in the javascript?

Terminal also looks fine, showing this:

```
[03/Aug/2023 15:28:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1445
[03/Aug/2023 15:28:37] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1521
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Editor</title>
    <style>
        img {
            max-width: 400px;
            max-height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Image Editor</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'edit_image' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="previewImage(event)">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload and Edit">
    </form>

    <div id="imagePreview">
        <h2>Uploaded Image Preview:</h2>
        <img id="preview" src="" alt="Uploaded Image">
    </div>

    {% if edited_image %}
        <h2>Edited Image:</h2>
        <img src="{{ edited_image.url }}" alt="Edited Image">
    {% endif %}

    <script>
        function previewImage(event) {
            const fileInput = event.target;
            const imagePreview = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
            const preview = document.getElementById("preview");

            if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
                const reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    preview.src = e.target.result;
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
                imagePreview.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                preview.src = "";
                imagePreview.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import os
import uuid

def index(request):
    edited_image = None

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['image_file']:
        image_file = request.FILES['image_file']

        # Process the uploaded image using Pillow
        edited_image = process_image(image_file)

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'edited_image': edited_image})

def process_image(image_file):
    image = Image.open(image_file)

    # Image processing logic using Pillow or OpenCV can be done here.
    # For simplicity, let's just save the edited image and return its path.

    # Example: Converting the image to grayscale
    edited_image = image.convert('L')

    # Generating a new random filename for the edited image
    edited_image_name = f"edited_image_{uuid.uuid4().hex}.jpg"
    edited_image_path = os.path.join('media', edited_image_name)
    edited_image.save(edited_image_path, format='JPEG')

    return edited_image_path
```

project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('image_editor.urls'))
]

# Serve media files during development
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'image_editor',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoPhotoEditor.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'image_editor'/'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoPhotoEditor.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Answer (score 0):

In views.py

```
def process_image(image_file):
.
.
.
edited_image_path = os.path.join('media', edited_image_name)
.
.
.
return edited_image_path
```

os.path.join returns a string. You add this string to the context and then inside the template you attempt to access edited_image.url which does not exist.

As an aside, you are hardcoding the location as 'media' rather than using the media location you have set in settings.py. I recommend changing this to

```
from myProject import settings # <- change to your project name
edited_image_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, edited_image_name)
```

As far as your main problem goes there are a number of methods of getting a url.  A simple solution that should work with your existing code (not tested) would be to change the index method of your view code as follows:

```
def index(request):
edited_image = None

if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['image_file']:
    image_file = request.FILES['image_file']

    # Process the uploaded image using Pillow
    edited_image = process_image(image_file)
    edit_image_url = request.build_absolute_uri(edited_image)

return render(request, 'index.html', {'edited_image_url': 
edited_image_url})
```

Then in your template replace:

```
<img src="{{ edited_image.url }}" alt="Edited Image">
```

with:

```
<img src="{{ edited_image_url }}" alt="Edited Image">
```